# MS Access Date problem , how to compare date

Tags: ms-access, date

I would like to compare 2 date, which stored in database as String.
When I compare the date, I must convert them to date first, right? I know the ms access function datevalue() would convert a string to a date, but I am not sure what it will return, in other words, I don't know how access treats different parts of a string date.

For example, when I pass "11/12/2010" to datevalue, I would expect a date meaning Dec 11, 2010. And when I pass "12/11/2010", I also want to make sure it turns out to be Dec 22, 2010 so that my calculation works. I don't want ms access to interpret it as Nov, 12, 2010.

Ms access' datevalue() function doesn't need me to give any extra information about this.

Please give me some clues, thanks.

Comment: I'm confused.  Did you really say that you **DO** want 11/12/2010 to evaluate to Dec 11, 2010, but you **DO NOT** want 12/11/2010 to evaluate to Nov 12, 2010?  Surely you mistyped that.

Comment: The first thing you should do is STOP STORING DATES AS STRINGS. I assume that's a possibility of course, as it might be that you're dependent on an outside data source. I would expect that DateValue() would convert a string to a date based on your regional settings -- that is, you've got US regional settings, 11/12/2010 is November 12, and if you've got, say, UK regional settings, it would be December 11. But this is one of the huge pitfalls of trying to convert between string representations of dates -- you're better off just using REAL date data types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [DateValue Function](https://web.archive.org/web/20130315215339/http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/datevalue-function-HA001228814.aspx) (Archived):

> *If date is a string that includes only numbers separated by valid date separators, DateValue recognizes the order for month, day, and year according to the Short Date format you specified for your system.*